# Problem with Wifi Usb dongle Netgear WNA1000Mv2 on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: usb, realtek-wireless, netgear

I'm having troubles such as low speed, disconnecting very often, not recognising wifi networks with my Usb dongle NetGear.

I'm wondering if there is some conflict going on, or how I can install some drivers to make it work better.

Output of lsusb:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0846:9043 NetGear, Inc. WNA1000Mv2 802.11bgn [Realtek RTL8188CUS?]
```

I read some posts and checked the state of rtl8192cu. It seems that it is the right module dealing with the usb. But I don't know what to do with that.

Output:

```
modinfo rtl8192cu | grep 9043:

alias:    usb:v0846p9043d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install a driver this way

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192cu.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu
sudo dkms install rtl8192cu/0.1
```

Comment: I did it verbatim. Unfortunately it didn't work and it's even worse: now my usb key is not even recognised when i plug it in.

Comment: that's really strange...its light does not turn anymore on, however lsusb still detects it when it is plugged in...

Comment: You can remove it by `sudo dkms remove rtl8192cu/0.1`

Comment: And did you reboot?

Comment: i tried to remove the driver, i had "error! invalid number of parameters passed. Usage: remove <module>/<module-version> --all or remove <module>/<module-version> -k <kernel-version>

Comment: Oh, sry `sudo dkms remove rtl8192cu/0.1 --all`

Comment: Error! There are no instances of module: rtl8192 0.1 located in the DKMS tree

Comment: `rtl8192cu`, not `rtl8192`.

Comment: sorry! i rebooted, the usb key light went on again, but the problem with the wifi is not solved...

Comment: any ideas about it?

Comment: No ideas, sorry

Comment: so maybe it's just the usb key, but that's strange

Comment: do you think that it depends on some other module, or is rtl8192cu the right one? sorry about these silly questions...

Comment: This is not a silly question. It is not quite obvious. But yes, this module is supposed to support your dongle.